# Can find's -newermt accept epoch time?

Tags: bash, find

I seek to find files made after a specific time similar to how this command does it:

```
find . -type f -newermt '1/30/2017 0:00:00'
```

except instead of a date, and time, string, I need the time stamp to be in epoch time as read from the EPOCHSECONDS system variable. Can this be done? Or will it be necessary to convert EPOCHSECONDS to a date and time string?

I am asking because in a shell script I need to set a variable value equal to EPOCHSECONDS, do some commands that will make changes to unknown files, and then use the find command to see what files those commands changed.

Comment: It might be more straightforward to just touch a temporary file, do your commands, then find files simply `-newer` than the temporary file.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes it can.

The `-newerXY` entry of `man find` tells us that

> ```
> Time specifications are interpreted as for the  argument
> to  the -d option of GNU date.
> ```

and from the `info 'date input formats'` node:

> ## 29.9 Seconds since the Epoch
>
> If you precede a number with ‘@’, it represents an internal timestamp
> as a count of seconds.  The number can contain an internal decimal
> point (either ‘.’ or ‘,’); any excess precision not supported by the
> internal representation is truncated toward minus infinity.  Such a
> number cannot be combined with any other date item, as it specifies a
> complete timestamp.

So for example

```
find . -type f -newermt @1485752400
```

or

```
secs=$(date +%s -d '1/30/2017 0:00:00')
find . -type f -newermt "@$secs"
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The epoch time I need to pass to find will be stored in a variable. The example you have given uses a numeric literal. By what syntax can a variable containing an epoch time value be passed to find? Can this variable be prefixed by @ just as the literal is in your example?

Comment: @Stephen yes it can - see edit